# What's the correct import of Menu and MenuItem when using appCompat in Android?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-menu, appcompatactivity

I previously used ActionBarSherlock, but now I'm moving all my apps to the Material Theme using appCompat. I'm getting an UnsupportedOperationException with my code below:

```
 MenuItem num = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.num);

        num.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                //wow
            }
```

I'm getting an error of:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItemImpl.java:740)
```

So what should I do in this case? Should my Menu and MenuItems import from some other package? Or do I just need to use a different all together with MenuCompat and MenuItemCompat. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [setOnActionExpandListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setOnActionExpandListener(android.view.MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener)) was added only in API level 14. Therefore you can't use it safely as it does not exist in API levels lower than 14.

In your case, as suggested by the error message, you should use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener().

Comment: Interesting. I've used it all the way down to API 10 with ABS I guess. I see from the error message that I should use compat, but throughout my application which import should I use?

Comment: Whenever you need to use a method that was added later to MenuItem, you should use the static methods from MenuItemCompat, importing it with `import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;` . The imports for Menu and MenuItem themselves are the regular ones: `import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;`

Comment: Weird. So I don't use MenuCompat and MenuItemCompat in my code? How would I fix the issue I'm having then with `num.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {`

Comment: Oh. You meant `MenuItem setOnActionExpandListener (MenuItem item, MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener listener)` Gotcha. I thought you just wanted me to use the setOnAction... from MenuItemCompat class instead of MenuItem class.

Comment: I was actually suggesting you to use the setOnActionExpandListener from MenuItemCompat indeed, like this for example: 
`MenuItem num = menu.findItem(R.id.num);
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(num, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                return false;
            }
        });`